# Q-Tec Webcam 100 (093a:2460) video quality is horrible at best

Tags: 11.04, webcam, cheese

I just bought a new usb webcam for my desktop setup of Ubuntu Natty Narwhal. I plugged it in, started up Cheese, and saw my smiling face. But it was green and lined, very poor quality overall. I am skeptical that this is due to a poor quality webcam. :P

I tried it in Skype, Google+, and Gchat, but all of those showed only a black screen. They recognized the webcam as present, but showed no stream from it.

Kamoso showed a black screen as well, and Camorama had even poorer quality than Cheese.

Here are the details for the webcam from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 093a:2460 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Q-TEC WEBCAM 100
```

Am I missing a driver, or are there settings somewhere I need to tweak?

Answer (score 1):

Running `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype` should launch Skype with a fix for black webcam. You can also modify the launcher to do it automatically.

Also looking at [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SkypeWebCams), it seems that your webcam isn't properly supported. You should have looked at that page before buying.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 12.04

64 bits**

For the following camera to work:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2460 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Q-TEC WEBCAM 100
```

I had to:

1. `sudo apt-get install libv4l-0`
2. `locate v4l1compat.so`

The locate returned two files, I tried the x64 version, but din't work, so I issued the command to preload that file:

```
env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

And skype now works well with my camera.

<sub>**Notes:**</sub>
<sub>Please note that gstreamer-properties helped me confirm that my camera was working.</sub>
<sub>`gstreamer-properties`</sub>
<sub>And don't forget to add your user to the *video* group</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands

```
sudo modprobe -r gspca
sudo modprobe -r zc0301
sudo modprobe gspca
```

Comment: The response to each is:

`FATAL: Module [gspca|zc0301] not found.`

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Wrong model i guess.